# Eventmachine failed to work when system time changed earlier

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

When running the following popular eventmachine example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine-le'  
EM.run do  
  p = EM::PeriodicTimer.new(1) do  
    puts "Tick ..."  
  end  

  EM::Timer.new(100) do  
    puts "BOOM"  
    p.cancel  
  end  

  EM::Timer.new(120) do  
    puts "The googles, they do nothing"  
    EM.stop  
  end  
end
```

If the system time changed earlier, for example, change the system date from 2013.10.12 to 2013.10.10, the program stops immediately. Is there bugs in the Eventmachine project or something else wrong? Need your help. THX~

Comment: Answer would depend on EM reactor implementation I suppose - there are currently three: java, C and pure ruby

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least one implementation of `EM` is time-dependant (the java implementation for example stores unix timestamp of next event, if timestamp changed on server so will event execution)